# saving contents of echo output to variable in non-bash script

Tags: shell

I'm used to doing something like this in my bash scripts to echo output to a variable:

```
myvar=`echo $OSTYPE`
echo "my os is of type: ${myvar}"
```

On this current project however I'm using sh, which on my Ubuntu instance doesn't appear to be symlinked to bash.  I say that because the above code echoes nothing for `${myvar}` when I have the /bin/sh shebang at top.

So I assume `echo $OSTYPE` is not the way to go in sh?  If not, how can I do something similar?  (I've tried to echo `$(myvar)` but that didn't work either.)

Comment: It's not the way to go in any shell language. `myvar="$OSTYPE"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to work just fine in my `sh` :

```
$ myvar="test"
$ echo "My var is $myvar."
My var is test.
```

There is no need to `echo` the value of the variable and catch it again in another. [Here is a little bit more information on variable assignments](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varassignment.html).

**The thing is**, `OSTYPE` is not defined in `sh`'s environment. You'll have to pass it when running your script. So, instead of running...

```
$ /bin/sh yourscript.sh
or
$ ./yourscript.sh
```

You should run:

```
$ OSTYPE=$OSTYPE /bin/sh yourscript.sh
or
$ OSTYPE=$OSTYPE ./yourscript.sh
```

Of course, this assumes that the parent shell, in which you type the above command, has an `OSTYPE` variable. While `bash` does, it is not the case of every shell. Instead of `$OSTYPE`, you might however be able to use `uname`:

```
$ OS=$(uname -o)
$ echo "My OS is $OS."
My OS is GNU/Linux.
$ echo "My OS is $(uname -o)."
My OS is GNU/Linux.
```

On my machine, this sets the `OS` variable to `GNU/Linux`, instead of `linux-gnu` (which is the content of my `OSTYPE`).

**As a side note**, I'm guessing an equivalent of your code could be :

```
$ myvar="$(echo $OSTYPE)"
$ echo "My var is $myvar."
My var is linux-gnu
```

Comment: Thank you.  I don't suppose there's an OSTYPE semi-equivalent outside of the bash/bourne shell?  Maybe uname will do?

Comment: @jkj2000 You could use `$(uname -o)` instead. I updated my answer.